# check the last commit message in subversion

Tags: svn, version-control, command-line

Why is it when I execute the following command just after making a commit I get the commit message, but all other times I just get a line of dashes?

```
svn log -r head
```

Quite often I want to browse to a branch in my filesystem, check what branch it represents in subversion and check what the last commit message was, but this command only seems to work when I run it *just* after making a commit.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to get the last commit message of a branch try this :

```
svn log -l 1 BRANCH_URL
```

The `-l 1` is here to limit the size of the log to the last message.

If you want to check the last message of commit in your current working copy, try this :

```
svn log -r COMMITTED
```

Comment: Interestingly, there seems to be a delay before `svn log -r COMMITTED` returns the last commit message after you make a commit. For example, I committed r694, but for a minute or two after committing it still displayed r693 as the last commit.

Comment: @crmpicco : in the same working copy ? this is pretty strange, which version of svn do you use ?

Comment: Same for me; `svn log -r COMMITTED` and `svn log` return the r58 commit message but `svn log -r HEAD` returns the r59 message which is the one I entered last. I'm using svn 1.6.11.

Comment: Same as @u_Ltd. ... `HEAD` is the most recent, `COMMITTED` is showing the revision before (SVN version 1.9.4).

Comment: @crmpicco I found out why this is: Commited changes are remote - you need to do `svn up` (after committing) and then your `svn log` will be up to date. Fixes also the behavour @u_Ltd. mentioned.